# Put a numpy array of lists inside a numpy matrix at corresponding positions

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have the following numpy array containing lists inside

```
example=np.array(([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6,7]]))

print(example)
[list([1, 2, 3]) list([4, 5]) list([6, 7])]
```

I would like to put these values at the corresponding values of a numpy array of any suitable size. For example, I have the following matrix:

```
[[14021982. 14021982. 14021982.]
[14021982. 14021982. 14021982.]
[14021982. 14021982. 14021982.]]
```

Therefore, I want the output to be

```
[[1. 2. 3.]
[4. 5. 14021982.]
[6. 7. 14021982.]]
```

Is there an efficient way to that in python no matter the size of the two matrices sizes?

**EDIT: I also want to know if is that possible to do that for a matrix of smaller size:**

for example, I want to put the input

```
print(example)
[list([1, 2, 3]) list([4, 5]) list([6, 7])]
```

In the following matrix

```
  [[14021982. 14021982.]
  [14021982. 14021982.]
  [14021982. 14021982.]]
```

which would result in

```
    [[1. 2.]
    [4. 5.]
    [6. 7.]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace values by indices

```
example = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
target = np.array([...])

for i, j in enumerate(example):
    size = min(len(j), len(target[i]))
    target[i][0:size] = j[:size]

print(target)
```

Output

```
target = np.array([[14021982, 14021982, 14021982],
                   [14021982, 14021982, 14021982],
                   [14021982, 14021982, 14021982]])

[[       1        2        3]
 [       4        5 14021982]
 [       6        7 14021982]]

---------------------------------------------------------

target = np.array([[14021982, 14021982],
                   [14021982, 14021982],
                   [14021982, 14021982]])

[[1 2]
 [4 5]
 [6 7]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your approach works only for the 3x3 matrix I showed. What happens if the matrix is smaller than the maximum lenght of the numpy array of lists? could you please check my edit? thanks again!